# Correct way to use buttons in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibutton

I am creating my second app but first iOS game. I am all done with coding and levels.

But at the end I am struggling to use the buttons in sprite kit so I can create share, like, or to implement setting menu in it, the one way I am using is proving below.

```
  Button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
  Button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
  Button.center = CGPoint(x: (self.view?.frame.width)! - 30, y: 60)
  Button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), for: UIControlState.normal)
  Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PauseGame), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
  self.view?.addSubview(Button)
```

Now the problem with this button is that it is always enable and displayed, no matter what screen or scene I am in.

Is there is any other way of using the buttons?

Or maybe I have to use storyboard in SpriteKit project for all the settings, menuscreen, and extra buttons (e.g. Like, share)?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `UIKit` in **SpriteKit**. This is why the button isn't being removed when the scene is changed. The line:

```
self.view?.addSubview(Button)
```

Adds the button to the **view**, not **scene**. This is important because the view controller displays the scenes on the view, so you have 1 view (usually) that is displaying scenes. When you add the button to the view, it's actually attached to the view, not scene. To add a button node to a **scene**, try this:

```
let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Paused")
button.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
button.position = CGPoint(x: (self.view?.frame.width)! - 30, y: 60)
// Whatever else you want to do when setting up the button node
addChild(button)
```

The important line here is:

```
addChild(button)
```

Because it adds the `SKSpriteNode` to the **scene**. This means that when transitioning from scene to scene, the button will no longer stay in a fixed position, and will transition with the scene.